# initialise an OpenCL object

Tags: c, opencl

Hi I was wondering if I can create an openCL object like this struct

```
struct Product
{

    int n_id;
    char n_name;

    Item(id, name){n_id = id; n_name = name;}
} item;
```

I was wanting to pass in this information to a kernel to make the struct re-usable from another struct.

I want to add items via a kernel

```
kernel addItem(int name, char name)
{
    Item it(id,name);
    Items.add(it);
}
```

So my question is how do I pass this information over and how to I make the objects that I create re-usable from another kernel?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCL kernels are written in a restricted (e.g. no pointers in structs) and extended (e.g. float4 data type) C99 like language.  They are not written in C++.

You initialize C like structures on the host and then copy them over.  C like structures don't have methods.  Using the C++ OpenCL bindings (from cl.hpp) on the host with Visual Studio I do something like this:

```
#pragma pack(16)
struct Light {
    cl_float4 pos;
    cl_float4 dir;
    cl_float4 intensity;
    cl_int type; 
    cl_int pad[3];
};
#pragma pack()

const int nlight = 10
Light lights[nlight];
//...code to initialize array of structs

cl::Buffer lights_mem = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,  sizeof(Light)*nlight, lights);

kernel1.setArg(0, lights_mem);
```

That copies the lights to the OpenCL device.  In the kernel you can access the struct of lights like this:

```
__kernel void trace(__global Light* lights, ...) {
    float4 pos = lights[0].pos
    //find a new position (pos_new)
    lights[0].pos = pos_new;
```

When the kernel finishes you can pass cl::Buffer lights_mem to the next kernel.

```
kernel2.setArg(0, lights_mem);
```

However, you can get better speeds by using read only or write only buffers so it may help to separate your kernels into those that read only and those that write only.

I don't know if the pack() pragma and padding are still necessary but I keep using them because everytime someone says they are not necessary anymore I get a problem which goes away when I put them back.

Comment: Worth noting that the (non-portable) static c++ kernel language by AMD can be used to write C++-like structs and classes in OpenCL kernels. The usual restrictions still apply (and this includes: no inheritance or virtual functions, no pointers in structs/classes, etc...). Of course, it only works with the AMD runtime. +1 for the last paragraph, packing is definitely a headache. I was able to take them out from my renderer last night actually but I'm still apprehensive it's going to blow up in my face at some point.

Comment: Oh that's interesting.  I did not know about that.  I only use OpenCL 1.1 and #define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS so that my code works on both Nvidia and AMD.

Comment: I actually don't use the static c++ kernel language, I was only mentioning it :p (and the CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_1_APIS is definitely useful, otherwise it's almost impossible to run 1.1 on 1.2 runtimes because of missing or wrong function signatures - so irritating). I wish NVIDIA would implement OpenCL 1.2, though, how hard can it be?

Comment: I don't think Nvidia is interested in OpenCL anymore.  I'm pretty sure they broke the OpenCL drivers on their Titan card on purpose.  Actually, I think they still work if you don't enable the double floating point boost (but I don't know for sure).  That just means, for OpenCL, the Titan is slower than the GTX690 but cost just as much.

Comment: You guys are legends! This is all awesome info exactly what I want and some great info

Mad props to @raxman